# I want to resize a Plane geometry from the corner points. Three.js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want to resize a Plane geometry from the corner points. It works fine since rotation is not included in my calculations inside the function. When the rotation goes above a certain value (e.g. above 45 degrees) the resizing starts to get ridiculous.

0 degree resizing:
[image: 0 degree resizing]

70 degree resizing:
[image: 70 degree resizing]

Here's my code:

```js
import { Edges } from "@react-three/drei";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { DoubleSide, Vector3 } from "three";
import { CORNER_SCALE } from "../../../../../consts";
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { DEG2RAD } from "three/src/math/MathUtils";

import { Edges } from "@react-three/drei";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { DoubleSide, Euler, Matrix4, Vector3 } from "three";
import { CORNER_SCALE } from "../../../../../consts";
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { DEG2RAD } from "three/src/math/MathUtils";

const rotatePoint = (p, angleX, angleY, angleZ) => {
  const point = new Vector3(p.x, p.y, p.z);
  const rotationMatrix = new Matrix4();
  rotationMatrix.makeRotationFromEuler(new Euler(angleX, angleY, angleZ));
  point.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);
  return point;
};

const translatePoint = (point, dx, dy, dz) => {
  // Create a new point object to avoid modifying the original
  const translatedPoint = [point[0] + dx, point[1] + dy, point[2] + dz];

  return translatedPoint;
};

const DemoPlane = ({ r, cameraControlsRef }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([0, 0, 0]);
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState([0, 0, DEG2RAD * 60]); // [0, 0, 0]
  const [boxGeo, setBoxGeo] = useState([1, 1, 1]);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState([1, 1, 1]);
  const [cornerPointScale, setCornerPointScale] = useState(CORNER_SCALE);
  const [cornerPositions, setCornerPositions] = useState([]);
  const [cornerIndex, setCornerIndex] = useState(null);
  const [isResizing, setIsResizing] = useState(false);

  const { camera } = useThree();
  const planeRef = useRef();
  const containerPlaneRef = useRef();

  const handlePointer = (e, op, i) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    switch (op) {
      case "corner-down":
        setCornerIndex(i);
        setIsResizing(true);
        break;
      case "up":
        setIsResizing(false);
        break;
      case "move":
        if (isResizing) {
          let pointer = e.point;
          pointer = rotatePoint()
          switch (cornerIndex) {
            case 0:
              const newWidth =
                boxGeo[0] - (pointer.x - cornerPositions[cornerIndex][0]);
              const newHeight =
                boxGeo[1] + (pointer.y - cornerPositions[cornerIndex][1]);

              if (newWidth < 0 || newHeight < 0) return;

              const deltas = {
                x: -(newWidth - boxGeo[0]) / 2,
                y: (newHeight - boxGeo[1]) / 2,
                z: 0,
              };
              // const newPosition = translatePoint(
              //   position,
              //   deltas.x,
              //   deltas.y,
              //   deltas.z
              // );
              const [dX, dY, dZ] = rotatePoint(
                deltas,
                rotation[0],
                rotation[1],
                rotation[2]
              );
              const newPosition = translatePoint(position, dX, dY, dZ);
              setBoxGeo([newWidth, newHeight, boxGeo[2]]);
              setPosition(newPosition);
              break;
            case 1:
              break;
            case 2:
              break;
            case 3:
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const pos = planeRef.current.geometry.attributes.position;
    const corners = [];
    for (const i of [...Array(4).keys()]) {
      const vector = new Vector3();
      vector.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
      const corner = planeRef.current.localToWorld(vector);
      corners.push(corner);
    }
    // console.log(corners.map((c) => [c.x, c.y, c.z]));
    setCornerPositions(corners.map((c) => [c.x, c.y, c.z]));
    // console.log(initialCornerPositions);
    cameraControlsRef.current.rotateTo(rotation[2], rotation[0], false);
  }, [position, planeRef.current, rotation]);

  return (
    <>
      <mesh
        ref={containerPlaneRef}
        position={[position[0], position[1], position[2] - boxGeo[2] / 2]}
        rotation={[0, 0, rotation[2]]}
        scale={100}
        visible={false}
        onPointerMove={(e) => handlePointer(e, "move")}
        onPointerUp={(e) => handlePointer(e, "up")}
        onWheel={() => {
          setCornerPointScale(8 / camera.zoom);
        }}
      >
        <planeGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
        <meshBasicMaterial color={"black"} side={DoubleSide} />
      </mesh>

      <mesh
        ref={planeRef}
        position={[position[0], position[1], position[2] + boxGeo[2] / 2]}
        rotation={[0, 0, rotation[2]]}
        scale={scale}
      >
        <planeGeometry args={[boxGeo[0], boxGeo[1]]} />
        <Edges color={"#fff"} />
        <meshBasicMaterial
          color={"yellow"}
          side={DoubleSide}
          transparent
          opacity={30 / 100}
        />
      </mesh>

      {cornerPositions.map((position, i) => (
        <mesh
          key={i}
          position={position}
          scale={cornerPointScale}
          onPointerDown={(e) => handlePointer(e, "corner-down", i)}
        >
          <sphereGeometry args={[1, 32, 16]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color="red" transparent />
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default DemoPlane;
```